# MFC MDI Tabs are enumerated

Tags: windows-7, mfc, tabs

I have an MFC (VS2010) MDI application (created by the wizard).
I want that each tab will be created with the same label and not enumerated value (i.e the tab's caption should always be "New Tab" and not "New Tab 1" ... "New Tab N".

I want this option since upon the creation of a new tab (each tab is holding CHtmlView) I'm changing his caption to the HTML title (like browsers act). 
So now when I create the first tab it gets "New Tab 1" and I change it to be "MyCaption" when I open another tab the 1st receives "New Tab 1" the 2nd (newly opened) receives "New Tab 2" I change it to "MyCaption" but going to the first tab again causes the 2nd tab to be called "New Tab 2". How can I disable this mechanism?

Thanks a lot,

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CDocument::SetTitle to permanently change the title displayed in the tab.